# Excel attachment name contains its path name in android using mail.jar

Tags: android, email, email-attachments

I am creating an excel file from my android app and have to send it as attachment in email using mail.jar but attachment name consists //mnt/sdcard/MyExcel.xls which i don't want. I want attachment to be MyExcel.xls.

Thanks in advance.

enter code here

```
filepath="//mnt/sdcard/MyExcel.xls";
Mail m = new Mail("f@f.c", "xxxx");
        m.setBody("Body");
        m.setSubject("Subject");

        try 
        {
            m.addAttachment(filepath);

        }
        catch (Exception e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
m.setTo("s@s.s"); 

            m.setFrom("f@f.c"); 
            try 
            { 

                if(m.send()) 
                {
                    mailingStatus = true;
                }
                else 
                { 
                    mailingStatus = false;
                } 
            } 
            catch(Exception e) 
            { 
                mailingStatus = false;
            }
```

Comment: Mail.jar is an external library used for sending mails,

Comment: I assumed it is, but without more information regarding this external library, how do you expect someone to know how to specify the name of a multipart *using this library*?